# Is a certification “gotten”, “earned”, or “obtained”?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, business-language

When you pass the exam for certification in ABC, which if any of these work, and which if any do not work?

1. You **get** a certification in ABC.
2. You **earn** a certification in ABC.
3. You **obtain** a certification in ABC.

Comment: Does anyone say "gotten" anymore except in "ill-gotten"?

Comment: @GEdgar: I haven't gotten any complaints about using it lately. (I've heard that Americans tend to use 'gotten' more than Brits.)

Comment: @GEdgar No, nobody ever uses *gotten* outside of *ill-gotten* — apart from 300,000,000 or so native speakers, plus or minus a few turncoats. :)

Comment: I wonder if these lines will cross one day... http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+was+got%2Cit+was+gotten&year_start=1860&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: Consider: “Once you pass the XYZZY exam, you will be certified in XYZZY.”

Comment: @GEdgar: [these lines](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+have+got%2C+I+would+have+gotten&year_start=1860&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) (note American English) have crossed.

Answer (score 4):

All of those, and also *receive*, "are given" and "are awarded". Without knowing anything else about the context, I'd lean towards "are awarded", as being more specific because it wouldn't apply to many other things you can receive/get/obtain/be given.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [COED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/certificate?view=uk), *certification* means

> an official document attesting a fact, in particular:
> • a document recording a person’s birth, marriage, or death: a birth certificate
> • a document confirming that someone has reached a certain level of achievement in a course of study or training: a university-accredited certificate
> • a document attesting ownership of an item or the fulfilment of legal requirements: a share certificate

The critical aspect of a certification (or a certificate) is to attest to a fact. That fact may be something that is ascribed or acquired, and if acquired, may be through the certification holders diligent efforts, or not.

You can certify that someone

- is female
- is 30 years old
- can read an eyechart while wearing glasses
- has attended class
- is disease free
- has the highest grade point average

There is obviously a wide range of affirmative efforts or accomplishments (or none) that may be the basis of receiving a certification.  Consequently, while some certifications may have been *earned*, many are not. They are *received, obtained, gotten, issued* or any other term that means *convey* without indicating an accomlishment on the part of the holder.

Comment: Assuming the exam mentioned is one that one would work for, rather than something like a medical exam, *earned* would be appropriate in this case.

Comment: @JonHanna No disagreement, but you need to know the context to determine whether *earned* is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in meaning. In spoken AmE, *get* seems to be common. *Obtain* seems to be a better fit in formal settings. And *earn* doesn't seem to be that common at all. *Earn* implies that you deserve the certificate because you have worked very hard to get it.